# Not able to download amazon app store despite having an intel i3 9100

Tags: android, windows, microsoft-store

Even though I meet the system requirements for the Amazon App Store, the Microsoft Store gives me the message 'This app will not work on your device.'. I am on i3 9100 and the required minimum processor is 8th gen.

[image: ImageImage]
[image]

Comment: As far as I know download of APKs via Amazon store in Win11 Android WSL environment is limited to certain countries.